# How do I search for error in a remote connection to windows with RDP?

Tags: windows, windows-10, remote-desktop

I'm trying to get a RDP connection to my workstation and is getting my certificate, the connection seems to work but I do only getting a black screen. RDP has worked before.

The only difference I can think of that I have done recently is installing a third screen.

It is a WAN connection and I can send a user account if needed that is blocked from doing anything but logging in with RDP.

I did make a conection on the WAN ip on the same network as the host and whasn't logged out on the host. The screen in RDC whas gray so somthing is weard.
I did try to conect with RDC on the local ip over LAN and it don't work.

Comment: Did you try updating the settings in the RDP to ensure correct screen size/resolution etc.

Comment: I did try 640*480 16bit

Comment: Are you able to test a differenet location. Can you RDP into another machine on same LAN?

Comment: I have try'ed it on a different location, it didn't work then. I didn't try different settings there.

Comment: I did try it with RDC on 2G, same thing. Tested admin session and fit res

Comment: Fit resulution. In this case I think it is 1080p